# How could I find out what kind of warnings get enabled when I use the warning-pragma?

Tags: perl, warnings, pragma

Is there a command or a variable that shows me all the different warnings which get enabled when I use the warning-pragma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[perldoc warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Category-Hierarchy) shows the hierarchy of categories warnings uses.  (Though before perl 5.20, this was in [perldoc perllexwarn](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.0/perllexwarn.html).)

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
perldoc perldiag
```

The output starts:

> #### NAME
>
> perldiag − various Perl diagnostics
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> These messages are classified as follows (listed in increasing order of desperation):
>
> `(W) A warning (optional).`
> `(D) A deprecation (optional).`
> `(S) A severe warning (enabled by default).`
> `(F) A fatal error (trappable).`
> `(P) An internal error you should never see (trappable).`
> `(X) A very fatal error (nontrappable).`
> `(A) An alien error message (not generated by Perl).`
>
> The majority of messages from the first three classifications above (W, D & S) can be controlled using the "warnings" pragma.